# (CKEDITOR4)I added a filter using filter.addTransformations but it didn't take effect

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

The requirement is that when the character `<p style="text-align:justify">&nbsp;</p>` exists in the editor, it needs to be converted into `<p>&nbsp;</p> through the filter` , the following is the program I wrote, but it did not run during the test, I hope my question can be answered, thank you!

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {

/* code */ 
ev.editor.on('filter', function(event) {
  var filter = event.data.filter;
  filter.addTransformations([[
    {
      element: 'p',
      attributes: { 'style': /^text-align:(justify)$/ },
      childRule: function(child) {
        if (child.name == '#text' && child.value == '\xa0') {
          return CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
        }
      }
    }
  ]]);
});
/* code */ 

})
```